# Headlights detection using Difference of Gaussian (DoG)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, gaussian

I am developing a project of detecting vehicles' headlights in night scene. First I am working on a demo on MATLAB. My detection method is edge detection using Difference of Gaussian (DoG): I take the convolution of the image with Gaussian blur with 2 difference sigma then minus 2 filtered images to find edge. My result is shown below:

Now my problem is to find a method in MATLAB to circle the round edge such as car's headlights and even street lights and ignore other edge. If you guys got any suggestion, please tell me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be able to get a better segmentation using a slightly different approach.

There is already strong contrast between the lights and the background, so you can take advantage of this to segment out the bright spots using a simple threshold, then you can apply some blob detection to filter out any small blobs (e.g. streetlights). Then you can proceed from there with contour detection, Hough circles, etc. until you find the objects of interest.

As an example, I took your source image and did the following:

1. Convert to 8-bit greyscale
2. Apply Gaussian blur
3. Threshold

This is a section of the source image:

[image: before]

And this is the thresholded overlay:

[image: after]

Perhaps this type of approach is worth exploring further. Please comment to let me know what you think.

Comment: 1. I cannot ignore the small blobs because headlights can be far away and streetlights can be much bigger. I intend to divide the picture into 2 parts: the upper and lower part contains streetlights and headlights, respectively and I just analyze the lower part. What do you think about my solution?
2. Is your threshold method similar to converting to binary image? Actually I am not allowed to do that
3. Could you tell me more specifically about how you circle the bright objects after threshold step? Can it be applied to DoG?
If you dont mind, could you send me your code? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3049831 Dividing the picture is fine, you can always analyse the largest "lowest" blobs, assuming there will be no smaller lights below the car. What do you mean by *"actually I am not allowed to do that"*? Are you solving a real problem or is this some kind of assignment with constraints?

Comment: I agree with Rowland, I would actually do something similar myself. Dividing the picture into 2 parts would help to speed up the process abit, so go for it. In regard to circling the bright objects after the threshold step, i think the red spots are done through a process called mask, go read it up, fairly simple.

Comment: its basically to zero everything except the ROI, which is the headlights, and then u can set a colour to it. hope I helped (:

Comment: @rockinfresh your advise is very helpful. I will try to test it

Comment: @RogerRowland yes it is truly an "assignment with constraints" and it annoys me a lot. 
Anyway, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Make sure to use the additional information you have on headlights which is **SYMMETRY**. A blob which is a suspect headlight should have (up to some error obviously and not exactly) a symmetric blob based on the position of the car, assuming the car is driving towards the camera. BTW, you should only check for symmetry in shape and not in intensity as one headlight might be different then its counterpart.